# How can automatically size a google map on my website?

Tags: css, html, height

I would like to place a google map on a webpage and have a couple textboxes in the `div` after it:

```
    <div id="map_area">
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="date_range">
      <input type="text" id="start_datepicker" />
      <input type="text" id="end_datepicker" />
    </div>
```

I want the text inputs to have an automatic height and the map_area/map_canvas to take up all the rest.  What `height` style do I need to set on the map_canvas.  So far, only percentages or heights in px work, but then the send div is either too big or too small.

Is there a setting that will let the second div be auto height and have the map's height be total-minus-second-div?

Comment: What do you mean auto height for text input?

Comment: Mr. Alien: I tried setting map_area to 80%, for example, but then there is too much space for the input boxes below.  I want the input elements to use up just the space they would normally use, like when I put a paragraph `<p>` before and after them.  And the map should use the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set your html and body tags to be height:100%.

Then set map_area to be ay height:90% and date_range to be 10%s.

Then set map_canvas to be height 100%.

In that way map_area and date_range will be taking up the full 100% of the available screen height and map_canvas will take up the full height of map_area.

Comment: But 10% is too large when the screen is big.  And when the browser window is small, 10% isn't enough to contain the `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used `display: table` for the body and `display: table-row` for the div element.  This worked pretty well, though the elements that I wanted to place were positioned behind the map's dynamic tiles.

In the end, I just made a `div` and put it on the map as Google suggests with "custom controls".  Easier and looks nice.